# What would be causing pygame.init() to take 40 seconds to execute?

Tags: python, performance, pygame, pygame2

Pygame was working perfectly last night, now the pygame.init() function is taking ~ 40 seconds to finish compared to being instant before.

```py
import pygame
import time
start = time.time()
pygame.init()
print(f"Runtime: {time.time() - start}")
```

Console results:

```
"C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" "D:/Google Drive/CompSci/proj/Alien Invasion/test.py"
pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.9.0)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Runtime: 40.15961766242981
```

Where normally the runtime should be almost instant...

I have exclusions in Windows Defender for all related folders:
[Windows Defender exlusions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiBcm.png)

Comment: [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/1573) looks like it has some good troubleshooting steps. Did you recently change anything related to display, input or audio hardware?

Comment: Ok I was able to narrow it down to pg.joystick.init(). After unplugging and plugging back in my keyboard the loading problem goes away...

Comment: Okay I'll post the resolution as an answer so you can upvote and/or accept it if you want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/1573), a troubleshooting step is to do all of the `init`s separately, like:

```
pygame.display.init()
pygame.mixer.pre_init(frequency=44100, size=-16, channels=2, buffersize=512, 
                      allowedchanges=pygame.AUDIO_ALLOW_ANY_CHANGE)
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.joystick.init()
```

This will make it obvious which one is slowing things down. In OP's case it was `joystick.init()` casuing the slowness, which was solved by disconnecting and re-connecting the keyboard.